# Correct way to store data in SQL database when columns are unknown

Tags: mysql, django

So the situation that I have is,I am developing a form builder like application which needs to be custom for all users. The form is hosted and response collected in database. Now what is the correct way to do the same in mysql like database.

For an example assume two forms, one with a text field and another with radio button and text field. Also once that model is created is there any way to use django forms, or will I have to go some other way.

Comment: you can use a jsonfield.

Comment: @e4c5 that would work. Thanks please add a answer and i will accept that . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently mysql introduced [JSON fields](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

> As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type that enables
>   efficient access to data in JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)
>   documents. The JSON data type provides these advantages over storing
>   JSON-format strings in a string column:

Even if you don't have the latest version of mysql it's still possible to save JSON data in a varchar field and is quite a popular solution supported by many [third party libraries](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/json-fields/) that provide JSON support for Django.

The reason that a third party library is needed is because Django doesn't have a built in JSONField. One has been added recently for Postgresql but mysql is still lagging behind.

Alternative that does not involve mysql is to use redis. Django has excellent support for [redis](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and as you know redis hashes are very similar to python dictionaries. ORM support requires third party libraries as with mysql json fields. However it's simpler to think of redis as a python dictionary that can be persisted across sessions and queried very fast. Last but not least the hash is just the tip of the iceberge.

Comment: one thing that i noticed in your answer is using redis. Isn't that mainly used as a cache. I have not come across a case till now where an application uses redis as primary dbs. First is it a good idea? if yes then does it has support with the django ORM itself ?

Comment: Though redis was originallly created as a cache it's now a fully featured key - value database (noSQL) it's blazing fast (since every thing is in memory) but data is also persisted to disk so it survives restarts. And you can even replicate the data just like you do in mysql. Since the comment is getting a bit long, added a bit to the answer too